# Transform dataframe format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I convert the following dataframe from df1 to df2?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a b c', '1 2 3', 2011], ['d e f', '4 5 6', 2012]])
#df1
           a       b     c
    0  a b c   1 2 3  2011
    1  d e f   4 5 6  2012


df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 2011], ['b', 2, 2011], ['c', 3, 2011],
['d', 4, 2012], ['e', 5, 2012], ['f', 6, 2012]])

#df2
   a  b     c
0  a  1  2011
1  b  2  2011
2  c  3  2011
3  d  4  2012
4  e  5  2012
5  f  6  2012
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example is ambiguous, please provide a DataFrame constructor.

Comment: Maybe [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Comment: as mozeay said , your example is not clear that you have a list in your a and b columns or a string

Comment: The column 'a' contains strings. The question has been updated. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try as follows. Apply [`.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to columns `a` and `b` in a loop, each time [`exploding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the result. This will get us 2 `pd.Series` and we use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to put them together. After this, we just need to assign col `c`, and reset the index. So:

```
import pandas as pd

# adding columns=['a','b','c'] to match data in your post:
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a b c', '1 2 3', 2011], ['d e f', '4 5 6', 2012]], columns=['a','b','c'])

res = pd.concat([df1[col].str.split(' ').explode() for col in ['a','b']], axis=1)

# change dtype for second col
res['b'] = res['b'].astype(int)

# assign column `c` and finally, reset index
res['c'] = df1['c']
res.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

print(res)

   a  b     c
0  a  1  2011
1  b  2  2011
2  c  3  2011
3  d  4  2012
4  e  5  2012
5  f  6  2012
```